# Error while installing pip using get-pip.py with Python2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am using Python2.7.10 on a Windows10 machine, and wish to install pip.

I followed the instructions from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to get the get-pip.py file, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence

I found that if I install an older version of pip (for Python2.6) then the installation is successful, and I can use pip regularly. If I try to use this older version (9.0.3) to install the newer one (18.0) then I get the same error message.

The complete log of the installation is below (1). If I manually install setuptools then I get the same message when it tries to download the next package:

Any assistance with installing the newer version will be much appreciated :-)

1)

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f4/385715ccc461885f3cedf57a41ae3c12b5fec3f35cce4c8706b1a112a133/setuptools-40.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (567kB)
    1% |Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence
```

**Update:** after installing several packages manually I was able to install the new pip version. It obviously didn't solve the problem, and pip is still not working. When trying to use it, the same error message appears at every attempted download. See log at (2). I double checked the address, and it appears to be correct.

2)

```
Collecting Requests
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
    11% |Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;qr - add the quiet flag (`-q`) to your command

While trying to debug I redirected the output to a file:

```
python -m pip install requests > .\temp.txt
```

Surprisingly, everything suddenly worked!

It appears there is a [known bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5665) (Thanks Matan M) while displaying the progress bar to the console. Basically, any solution that would avoid writing it would work.

Here are some options:

1. Use the `-q` flag
2. Turn off the progress bar using `--progress-bar off`
3. Redirect to a temp file

:-)

Comment: Thanks, 
I must say that I understood the problem from your comments and not from the link...  :)

Comment: Solved my problem with another package. According to the answer, I used: `python -m pip install -q package_name`

Answer (score 1):

Hi check if you added the relevant `python` paths to the `PATH`.

Comment: I added `C:\Python27` to my system's `PATH`. Are there any other paths I should add?

Comment: Make sure that there isn't any older python path in your PATH variables.

Comment: I checked both the User's variables and the System's. There is no other Python path in `PATH`. I also moved the right path up just to make sure I didn't miss anything...

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install <package> -q **or**
--progress-bar off
```